# Is sign function continuous in complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Is sign function continuous in the complex plane? Is it continuous everywhere except at $z = 0$ ? Is it continuous in a circle of unit radius and argument having $\exp(-i\theta)$ ?

Comment: How do you define $sign(x + iy)$? Do you define it as $sign(x)$?

Comment: You can define is as sgn(z) = |z|/z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{|z|}{z}$ is continuous in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ as it is the quotient of continuous functions. However, $\frac{|z|}{z}$ is obviously not defined in $z = 0$ (hence not continuous there either).

By the way, it is more common to use $\frac{z}{|z|}$ instead of $\frac{|z|}{z}$ because then you have $z = |z| \cdot \frac{z}{|z|}$ just like for the reals.

Comment: I don't think this is what you are saying, but I thought it was at first, so to avoid confusion: $\frac{|z|}{z} \neq \frac{z}{|z|}$.  For example $\frac{i}{|i|} = i \neq -i = \frac{|i|}{i}$

Comment: @Callus Thanks, I improved the wording.